# Azure virtual machine docker fails due to image size

Tags: azure, docker

On my Azure virtual machine, I am trying to install docker image and the process fails as one of the image is big.

```
$ docker image pull quantconnect/lean  
Using default tag: latest  
latest: Pulling from quantconnect/lean  
2b55860d4c66: Pull complete   
8e058277d049: Pull complete   
cac814e1eefd: Pull complete   
a298473404ba: Pull complete   
cbb32a5e1fa8: Pull complete   
ec88dd5ac36c: Pull complete   
8f720de37b38: Pull complete   
9766466431ab: Extracting  8.044GB/8.044GB  
e80c63b4187c: Download complete   
fdd7328065d4: Download complete   
bd0e5ed28832: Download complete   
80fcde351e81: Download complete   
66b0a12ba358: Download complete   
57947192519c: Download complete   
2c098594f55c: Download complete   
623fea5b900e: Download complete   
c3e6b0d58f7c: Download complete   
3561ea3e49b0: Download complete   
50fd9a1cfdc0: Download complete   
6917383f48c4: Download complete   
d74e070826fd: Download complete   
d1d6fce225c5: Download complete   
14bc78875e07: Download complete   
20b4365cb722: Download complete   
85114afc50b0: Download complete   
df49da7b9e78: Download complete   
8f44125f5e08: Download complete   
55a4549396f7: Download complete   
a39ba8f4cfd9: Download complete   
d93731d67aad: Download complete   
f219ea682bf0: Download complete   
6c21b2e8bf6d: Download complete   
4f4fb700ef54: Download complete   
failed to register layer: write  
 /root/.cache/pip/http/a/1/f/b/d/a1fbdb85d0542fb80d7c341db76c891c533b2c204bdeb4f235be375c: no space left on device  
Error: Something went wrong while pulling quantconnect/lean:latest, see the logs
above for more information
```

The problem always occurs in extracting this 8GB image.
This is a new virtual machine with overall lots of space.

```
$ df -h  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/root        29G  3.1G   26G  11% /  
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev  
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           789M  996K  788M   1% /run  
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock  
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/loop0       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2182  
/dev/loop2       41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20671  
/dev/loop1       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061  
/dev/sda15      105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi  
/dev/sdb1        16G   28K   15G   1% /mnt  
tmpfs           789M     0  789M   0% /run/user/1000
```

How to allocate space for wherever the temp directory on VM is? Its a one time space needed and as the actual programs are small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I changed the disk space to 256GB and docker pull worked ...
though the image size is 21.4GB only, probably at time of installation it needed much more to download and extract